# Python: Incorrect UTC Offset

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone-offset, pytz

The following code prints: `-1 day, 19:00:00` when New York is actually 5 hours behind UTC. What is wrong and how to fix it?

```py
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime(2022, 11, 23, 22, 30)
tz = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
print(tz.utcoffset(date))
```

Comment: Is 7pm the day before _not_ midnight UTC -5 hours?

Comment: Why would it be different? From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo.utcoffset), it _"Return offset of local time from UTC, as a timedelta object that is positive east of UTC. If local time is west of UTC, this should be negative."_. If your local timezone hasn't changed, why do you expect `utcoffset` to give you a different result?

Answer (score 0):

`tz.utcoffset(date)` returns a `datetime.timedelta` that should be added to a UTC datetime to get local time. Its a negative number for negative UTC offsets so that the addition works.

```
>>> import pytz
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> 
>>> date = datetime(2022, 11, 23, 22, 30)
>>> tz = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
>>> offset = tz.utcoffset(date)
>>> offset
datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=68400)
>>> date + offset
datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 23, 17, 30)
```

timedelta displays oddly. `days=-1, seconds=68400` means to go backwards 1 day and then forward 68400 seconds, giving you that -5 hours.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the offset as a string, you can use

```py
date = datetime(2022, 11, 23, 22, 30, tzinfo = zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('America/New_York'))
print(date.strftime('%z'))
```

This prints: `-0500`

I'm using Python 3.9 - not sure if the syntax is the same in your version.